# Does a professor respond to my request to work with me?

Tags: collaboration

I would like to write an article and present it to a professor abroad. Does he accept my request to read my article and submit it in the name of both of us as a co-authors (if he agrees with my article)?
In fact, I'm looking for a way to both publish my paper and use a partnership with a professor at  the other university. Is such a collaboration common and does the professor respond to my request?

Answer (score 7):

A decent professor will not submit your article under their name if they only read it.
You could ask.them if they want to work together with you on something (but you shoupd probably not contact them out of the blue, especially if they are higher ranked as you).

Comment: Can you explain more how I can work with them?

Comment: @Roja: you can discuss problems with them via email or skype, or divide your problem into two parts where each of you is an expert in exactly one.part.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, user 112604

Comment: @Roja I don't know your academic "rank" but as master's student I was looking for internships in research and found that I had much better chances of getting a response when contacting less senior people, than professors, e.g. group leaders, post docs who are more involved in the research day-to-day anyway.